# Resetting the scrolling to the top of a modal box and removing scrolling from the main page when the modal box is open

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I created a modal box and if I scroll down, close it and reopen it, it is reopened where I left it. I was tried the following code to reset it to the top on reopening but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

I'm also looking to stop prevent the main page from scrolling when the modal box is open. How can I do that?

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-dialogue">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-main">
        <h3>Placeholder</h3>
        <div class="img-text">
          <img src="placeholder.png" class="img-modal" />
          <p class="text-modal">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-text">
          <img src="placeholder.png" class="img-modal" />
          <p class="text-modal">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-content {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 85%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 75%; /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
    var span= document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    image[0].onclick = function () {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
    };

       image[1].onclick = function () {
      modal[1].style.display = "block";
    };

    span[0].onclick = function () {
      modal[0].style.display = "none";
    };

  span[1].onclick = function () {
 modal[1].style.display = "none";
    };
    
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modal) {
        if (typeof modal[index].style !== 'undefined') modal[index].style.display = "none";    
      };
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: Please use [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right, just made a mistake when attempting using jquery:

`$(".mondal-content".scrollTop(0))` misspelled classname and it should've been `$(".modal-content").scrollTop(0)` or better yet `$(modal).find(".modal-content").scrollTop(0)`

Here is a way doing it without jquery:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
{
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");

  for(let i = 0, modal, close; i < buttons.length; i++)
  {
    //modal ID is stored as data-modal attribute
    modal = document.getElementById(buttons[i].dataset.modal);
    if (!modal)
      continue;

    buttons[i].onclick = function (e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modal.querySelector(".modal-content").scrollTop = 0;
    };

    close = modal.querySelector(".close");
    close.onclick = function()
    {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("modal"))
    {
      event.target.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.modal-content {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 85%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 75%; /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img class="myImg" data-modal="myModal1" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/s1j_z7YCGft2EBNfnpXel8v02F8QkQKvp-_UjkR8SFaE5ciwPX9IugLMYvo_cCBzzuThRD7dVwwLO3H7XnvbD0JNnyVDmw_mPd8T5NH7yzQSSirZcA=w100" />
<a href="#" class="myImg" data-modal="myModal2" src="https://www.google.com/logos/2003/anzac_day_au.gif" title="works with anything">My Link</a>
<img class="myImg" data-modal="myModal3" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w100-h100-n-l50-sg-rj" />

<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-dialogue">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-main">
        <h3>Placeholder</h3>
        <div class="img-text">
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/s1j_z7YCGft2EBNfnpXel8v02F8QkQKvp-_UjkR8SFaE5ciwPX9IugLMYvo_cCBzzuThRD7dVwwLO3H7XnvbD0JNnyVDmw_mPd8T5NH7yzQSSirZcA=w500" class="img-modal" />
          <p class="text-modal">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-text">
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/s1j_z7YCGft2EBNfnpXel8v02F8QkQKvp-_UjkR8SFaE5ciwPX9IugLMYvo_cCBzzuThRD7dVwwLO3H7XnvbD0JNnyVDmw_mPd8T5NH7yzQSSirZcA=w500" class="img-modal" />
          <p class="text-modal">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-dialogue">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-main">
        <h3>Placeholder</h3>
        <div class="img-text">
          <img src="//www.google.com/logos/2003/anzac_day_au.gif" class="img-modal" />
          <p class="text-modal">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-text">
          <img src="//www.google.com/logos/2003/anzac_day_au.gif" class="img-modal" />
          <p class="text-modal">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-dialogue">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-main">
        <h3>Placeholder</h3>
        <div class="img-text">
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w450-h450-n-l50-sg-rj" class="img-modal" />
          <p class="text-modal">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-text">
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w100-h100-n-l50-sg-rj" class="img-modal" />
          <p class="text-modal">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. It is really helpful. My only issue is that I had to adjust my JS code as I will have several modal boxes and your solution wouldn't work now. Do you have any idea of what I could do? I updated my JS code above.

Thanks!